# php - Call to a member function find() on a non-object simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to get html code from a website ,I'm using this code to do so but I'm getting this error :
Call to a member function find() on a non-object

this is the code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$fileEndEnd = mb_convert_encoding("http://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/5192798/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%82%D9%81-%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A8%D9%87-%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B4%D8%AF", 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

$c=curl_init($fileEndEnd);
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'nginx-curl-blahblahblah' );
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$r=curl_exec( $c );
curl_close( $c );

$html = str_get_html($r);
foreach($html->find('div.body') as $e)
    $a= $e->outertext . '<br>';
```

the error is on this line :

```
foreach($html->find('div.body') as $e)
```

I'm sure the $r variable has the html code, I echo $r and get the full html code.

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: @sgtBOSE - yes. I was wondering about it as well but it seems it does.
Can you please make sure that `$r` isn't empty? (prior to the str_get_html function)

Comment: Can you please upvote and approve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because apparently `$html` isn't an `object`.

According to the API of [`simple-html-dom`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), the [`str_get_html`](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/blob/1.5.0/Src/Sunra/PhpSimple/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php#L88) function should return an object. However, when I was over-viewing the source code of that library I noticed the following code:

```
// get html dom from string
function str_get_html($str, $lowercase=true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    if (empty($str) || strlen($str) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        $dom->clear();
        return false;
    }
    $dom->load($str, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

So in case that the `$str` parameter is empty or in case that the length of that string is bigger than the MAX_FILE_SIZE constant - it would return `false` (and not an object). I believe that this might be the case.

To be honest, I would except that a popular library like simple-html-dom to have a more comprehensive api documentation.

Comment: It's easier to complain about lack of documentation than to contribute to it. So that's how it happens.

Comment: Not complaining, just mentioning. I have no problem "spending" 10 more minutes in looking at the source code in order to find out things by myself - I even believe it's better.